# Check and highlight duplicates from within SharePoint list

Tags: list, duplicate

I am currently re-designing a form for logging incidents in my team. I am using InfoPath 2013 and it is all based off a List.

One of the fields requires a customer account number to be entered. On the current form if you type the account number '000000000' for example and click off the text field, after a short pause, a message is displayed underneath highlighting (with links to) any other tickets that are logged with that account number.

I am struggling to replicate this on the new form. I can't access the old one through InfoPath to copy the content unfortunately.

Please can anyone provide guidance on how to replicate this feature into the new form?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done much InfoPath forms dev in a few years now, but basically, all that is happening here is that after the text field loses focus, a query is being fired out to your SharePoint list and is then bringing back any matching list items. In InfoPath, you can just create a new data connection to your SharePoint list and have it run the same way after your text field loses focus, the query being for list items that have AccountNumber eq '000000'.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Do you have any links or guidance to how to actually do this please? This is the first development of any kind I have done on SharePoint so I'm just making it up as I go along and following forums and youtube videos! I haven't managed to find anything specific to what I am trying to do here however. Perhaps I'm not using the right wording to describe it when searching...